# How can I set the uploaded picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, upload

My html code like this :

```
<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <button id="upload-add-product" class="icon-plus"></button>
        <input id="upload-file" type="file" style="display: none;" multiple/>
    </figure>
</div>
<div 
...
```

My javascript code like this :

```
 $("#upload-add-product").click(function(){
     $("#upload-file").click();
 });
 ...
```

Demo and full code like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/daq37/11/

My case like this :

- When I click the plus icon and select 2 image then 2 images it will appear in first box and second box. While the plus icon will move on the third box
- When I click the plus icon and select 5 image then 5 images that will appear from the first box to the fifth box. While the plus icon will be lost

How can I do it?

Comment: You should create elements dynamically

Comment: @Satpal, You can implement you answer in jsfiddle. Because I'm still confused to implement it

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through the array of images and then append each image to each box.

Comment: You can implement you answer in jsfiddle. Because I'm still confused to implement it